# A concrete dam of height 128 feet was built in gorge. One side $AB$ of the gorge slopes at an angle of $60^o$, the other side $CD$ at $45^o$.

Tags: geometry

I was wandering across the internet when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> A concrete dam of height 128 feet was built in gorge. One side $AB$ of the gorge slopes at an angle of $60^o$, the other side $CD$ at $45^o$. 
>   The bases of the dam are horizontal and rectangular in shape. The lower base is 1215 feet by 152 feet, and the upper base is 32 feet wide. 
>   How many cubic yards of concrete were required?

**My work**

I imagine that dam to look like this:

[image: (picture here)]

Delving deeper into the picture, it becomes like this:

[image: (picture here)]

Positioning the dam so it is easier to get the volume of this dam, it looks like this:

[image: (picture here)]

Notice that the it is easier to get the volume of the dam if we separate the shapes that makes up the dam, the red and the green part...

[image: (picture here)]

The green part's volume is pretty straightforward. We'll just use the formula $$V = BH$$ where $V$ is the volume of the figure, $B$ is the 
area of the base and $H$ is the height of the figure. Looking at the green part of the figure, the area of it's base is a trapezoid. The area would 
be $$A = \frac{1}{2}h(b_1 + b_2)$$ where $h$ is the height of plane, $b_1$ is the length of the upper base, and $b_2$ is the length of the lower 
base. With that in mind, the volume of the green part would be...

$$V=BH$$
$$V = \left( \frac{1}{2}h(b_1 + b_2)\right)(H)$$
$$V = \left( \frac{1}{2}(128 \space feet)(1013.1 \space feet + 1215 \space feet)\right)(32 \space feet)$$
$$V = 4563148 \space ft^3$$

The red part is pretty tricky, but solvable. Imagining the red part as a one part cut in halves, it becomes easier to get its volume. Getting the 
volume of the whole red part below:

[image: (picture here)]

$$V=BH$$
$$V = \left( \frac{1}{2}h(b_1 + b_2)\right)(H)$$
$$V = \left( \frac{1}{2}(128 \space feet)(1013.1 \space feet + 1215 \space feet)\right)(120 \space feet)$$
$$V = 17111808 \space ft^3$$

Now getting the volume of the red part we see, it is $\frac{V}{2}$ or $8555904\space ft^3$

The total volume of the dam would be $4563148 \space ft^3 + 8555904 \space ft^3$ or $13119052.8 \space ft^3$

It's not yet the final answer because it must be converted to cubic yards. Now converting from cubic feet to yards:

$$13119052.8 \space ft^3\left(\frac{0.3048 \space meters}{1 \space feet}\right)^3 = 371490.18 \space m^3 $$
$$371490 \space m^3 \left( \frac{1.0936 \space yards}{1 \space meter}\right)^3 = 485873.9 \space cubic \space yards$$

Is my solution, ladies and gentlemen, correct?

Comment: In the text, the lower base is 1215 feet long but in the drawing the upper base has that dimension.

Comment: @Seyed you're right....

Answer (score -2):

It is from  SOLID MENSURATION  book (page 137 problem no 48) by James Bland and you may see that in this link.

https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.205959/2015.205959.Solid-Mensuration#page/n17/mode/1up

FIRST SOLUTION:    Volume Of Prismatoid
$$\tan 300  =  x/128$$
$$x  =  73.9  \text{ ft}.$$
$$\tan 450  =  y/128$$
$$y  =  128 \text{ ft}.$$

---

$$L  =   x  +  y  + 1215$$
$$L  =  73.9 +  128  + 1215$$
$$L   =  1416.9  \text{ ft}.$$

---

$$\text{Mean Width }    =    (32   +  152)/2          =   92 \text{ ft}.$$
$$\text{Mean Length }    =  (1215  + 1416.9)/2    =   1315.95 \text{ ft}.$$

---

$$V   =  (h/6) [A_{\text{up}}  +  A_\text{down}  +  4A_m ]$$
$$V   =  (128/6) [  (1416.9)(32)+  (1215)(152)+  4(92)(1315.95)  ]$$
$$V   =  (128/6)   [ 45,340.8 +  184,680+  484,269.6 ]$$
$$V   =   15,238,195.2 \text{ ft}.3$$
$$V   =  15,238,195.2 \text{ ft}.3 (〖1 yd〗^3/〖27 ft〗^3 )$$
$$V  =  564,377.6 \text{ yd}.3$$
$$V  =  564,378 \text{ yd}.3\tag{$\neq$ Book answer: $561,230\text{ yd}.3$}$$

Comments:   The length of dam at $1416.9 \text{ ft}$.   It should be $1398.457 \text{ ft}$, 
                        or be reduced by $18.443\text{ ft}$ in order to satisfy book answer. $( V = 561,230 \text{ yd}.3 )$.

---

SECOND SOLUTION:    Volume of truncated prism:
V  =  Km
V  =  Aright section   x Average Lateral edge
V  =  [1/2  (a+b)h][(sum of lateral edges)/4]
V  =  [1/2  (32+152)(128)][(1215   +    1215   +   1416.9   +  1416.9)/4]
V  =  (11,776)(1,315.95)
V  =  15,496,627.2  ft.3
V  =  15,496,627.2 ft.3(〖1 yd〗^3/〖27 ft〗^3 )
V  =  573,949.1556 yd.3
V  =  573,949 yd.3      ( ≠ Book answer: 561,230yd.3  )

---

THIRD SOLUTION:    Volume of frustum of Regular Pyramid
V  =  1/3 [b +  B +  √bB]h
V  =  1/3 (32)(1416.9)+  (1215)(152)+  √((45,340.8)(184,680) )
V  =  1/3 [45,340.8 +  184,680 +  91,507.04314]  (128)
V  =  13,718,521.31 ft.3
V  =  13,718,521.31 ft.3(〖1 yd〗^3/〖27 ft〗^3 )
V  =  508,093.3818 yd.3
V  =  508,093 yd.3   ( ≠ Book answer: 561,230yd.3  )

Comment: I edited the first half. Now please delete your answer, look at how I improved the formatting of your first half, edit your second half, and then undelete your answer. For some quick reference, go [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the **MathJax Tutorial**. Also, write $\$$\neq$\$$ to generate $\neq$ and $\$$\times$\$$ to generate $\times$ and $\$$\sqrt{a}$\$$ to generate $\sqrt{a}$ ($a$ can be anything you want).